# OpenErp New Module

Tags: python, odoo, constraints

I can't find anywhere, what is actually a "group name" on OpenErp.

I'm trying to make a new app based on the warehouse management openerp application, but everytime I try to install it, it says

> Constraint Error
>
> The name of the group must be unique !

Anyone can shed some light on what this group could be?

Already searched in files for "group" and I've changed some `group_` names I found on the original objects by this module, but no success.

Edit:

What I'm trying to achieve with this is to have a copy of the "stock" module in order to edit and test without touching the original stock one.

These are minor changes, like for example field names, delete or adding some fields, etc...

Already changed all the group names and made a fresh new database.

For example I'd like to delete the "Accounting" tab of the product section in stock, but I guess it is related to the product.product object model, could I delete this tab without affecting all the product.product inherited objects in OpenErp?

[image: account_tab_openerp]

Comment: http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/04_security/#user-groups May this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your module is trying to create a record in the `res_groups` table with a name that matches one of the records already in that table. That violates a [unique constraint](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/7.0/view/head:/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py#L76) and fails the installation.

Look at your module's data XML files, and search for "res.groups". Look at the `category_id` and `name` fields, then check your database for other records in `res_groups` with the same values.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm going to try this, let's see if i can resolve the issue

Comment: Well i did changed all "stock_group" objects, still got the Constraint error, then i've changed the "base.group" from the "base module" (inherited in the app i guess) then i got an error saying that the VariableID is not declared in the system... don't know how can i solve this :(

Comment: i changed "base.group_user" to "base.group_usuario" then the system gave me the VariableID error

Comment: This is the exact error: "ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: base.group_usuario"

Comment: Try removing the "base." from the beginning of the group id, @user2089267. That means that you're trying to modify an existing group from the base module. If you add some snippets of your data file to the question, it might be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Well, it's actually the "stock" app from openerp, i'm just trying to have it as another app in order to make some modifications and don't touch the original one, being a core module i know it can be something very buggy to do.

Comment: For example, i just made that modification to the "base.user_group", deleted the "base." but it throws the same ID error as before, but this time it takes the folder name as an object. "ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: koci.group_user" koci is the name of the folder.

Comment: For example in product_view.xml: <group string="Stock and Expected Variations" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '=', 'service')]}" groups="group_user">
                 <label string="Cost Price" for="standard_price" align="1.0" groups="group_user"/>
                  <div groups="group_user">

Comment: Where "group_user" was "base.group_user" before

Comment: Can I make a gentle suggestion, @user2089267? Instead of dumping all the detail in these comments, edit your question and clarify it with more detail. Tell us what your goal is. It sounds like you are trying to copy the regular stock module, make some changes to it, and install your changed version. If so, put that in the question, and make sure that you don't have both the regular stock module and your copy installed in the same database. Go and check in the modules screen.

Comment: Oh, ok, sure, thank you very much, i'll do it for sure, thank you! And yes it's kind of my goal to copy the regular one with some changes. I'll edit my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As per error, you are trying to create group which is already exist. Please check the group name you want to create. Modify it and try to add your module again.

You can check group name in database also.